# Routing error while implementing create in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to rails.I am getting the following error while trying to implement a create action..

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"settings", :format=>nil}
```

My controller file is as follows:-

```
   @settings = Setting.new(params[:settings])

respond_to do |format|
  if @settings.save
    format.html { redirect_to @settings, notice: 'Setting was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @settings, status: :created, location: @settings }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @settings.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

My Routes.rb file is as follows:-

```
resources :settings do
    member do
     post 'add'
     post 'remove'
     get 'settings/id'
    end

    collection do
     get  'add'
     get  'list' 
     post 'get_settings'
     get  'get_settings'
    end
  end

  resources :settings
```

my rake routes has the following:-

```
      GET    /settings/get_settings(.:format
settings#get_settings
                      GET    /settings(.:format)
settings#index
                      POST   /settings(.:format)
settings#create
                      GET    /settings/new(.:format)
settings#new
                      GET    /settings/:id/edit(.:format)
settings#edit
                      GET    /settings/:id(.:format)
settings#show
                      PUT    /settings/:id(.:format)
settings#update
                      DELETE /settings/:id(.:format)
settings#destroy
                      GET    /settings(.:format)
settings#index
                      POST   /settings(.:format)
settings#create
                      GET    /settings/new(.:format)
settings#new
                      GET    /settings/:id/edit(.:format)
settings#edit
                      GET    /settings/:id(.:format)
settings#show
                      PUT    /settings/:id(.:format)
settings#update
                      DELETE /settings/:id(.:format)
settings#destroy
```

My create.html.erb is as follows:_

```
<%= form_for @setting  do |f| %>
  <% if @setting.errors.any? %>  
  <div id="errorExplanation">  
    <h2><%= pluralize(@setting.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this setting from being saved:</h2>  
    <ul>  
    <% @setting.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
      <li><%= msg %></li>  
    <% end %>  
    </ul>  
  </div>  
  <% end %> 
</br></br>


Id: <%= f.text_field :id %><br>
Name: <%= f.text_field :name %><br>


<%= f.submit "Create" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

My error log is:-

```
Started GET "/settings/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-12 18:57:09 +0530
Processing by SettingsController#new as HTML
  Rendered settings/new.html.erb within layouts/application (170.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1112ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>
"settings", :format=>nil}):
  app/views/settings/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_settings_new_html_erb__979995
802_23360592'
  app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:29:in `new'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.1
1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within resc
ues/layout (0.0ms)
```

My new.html:-

```
<h1>New setting</h1>




<%= form_for @setting  do |f| %>
  <% if @setting.errors.any? %>  
  <div id="errorExplanation">  
    <h2><%= pluralize(@setting.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this setting from being saved:</h2>  
    <ul>  
    <% @setting.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>  
      <li><%= msg %></li>  
    <% end %>  
    </ul>  
  </div>  
  <% end %> 
</br></br>


Id: <%= f.text_field :id %><br>
First Name: <%= f.text_field :name %><br>


<%= f.submit "Create" %>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<% end %>




<%= link_to 'Back', settings_path %>
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Why do you define `resources :settings` twice in your `routes.rb` ?

Comment: try rake routes and see what routes you have available

Comment: @arieljuod.i have updated the question

Comment: @Mischa It is post as i am trying to create

Answer (score 0):

A good start point is always to print out your routes via:

```
rake routes
```

Then you need to define a show method in the controller:

```
def show
  ..
end
```

And a view:

```
app/views/settings/show.html.erb
```

With the `resources :settings` he should recognize that there is a show path. Witch could look like this:

```
settings_path(user.id)
```

`resources :settings` dont needs to be included twice.

And it has nothing to do with your `UserController` i guess. The importend part is the `SettingController`. The error could appear if you display a SettingsShow link on the `/view/user/show.html.erb` ? (Not 100% sure, need to see more code, `SettingController` would be interessting).

Comment: As you can see in your routes the show path always needs an id with should be shown ( /settings/:id(.:format) ). So be sure you always access the show page with an id like settings_path(user.id). And be sure that you have defined a show method in your settings controller and that you have an show view.

Comment: can you specify where i have to put settings_path(user.id) in the index.html??

Comment: It was more generell you dont have to i guess. Sry for confusion. If you create a setting you end here: redirect_to @ settings witch is the view\setting\show.html.erb and it know the id from the @ setting object. Just be sure that there is an show method and the view itself!

Comment: So then please tell me what path you get in your browser when you receive the error.

Comment: Yeah but thats not the show page! So there must be a link to the show page inside the views/settings/new.html.erb somewhere. And that link needs to get an id!! like link_to "Show Settings", settings_path(@setting.id) as an example!

Comment: But if the path of the error page is settings/new and he tells you that there is no route for show then there must be an association right? In the end your problem is very very unclear. You need to tell us 100% correctly what you try, create user? create setting? does the error always look the same? do you got every code posted that we could need? Iam confused and lost now sry. I cant believe that you changed so much now and the error is still the same. Thats not possible. Leak of information.

Comment: @sg86..The error is still the same .if you want, you can check the error log which is being generated.I destroyed the model and controller and created it again but I am still getting the error. I too am completely lost and frustrated because after doing so much I should have got the solution to the problem.Please let me know if you can give me any other solution

Comment: ..please let me know if you can help in any way

Comment: Thats what i mean, the error log says  app/views/settings/new.html.erb:7 error in line 7 but the code is not posted here :( Its hard to help that way. Please post it, i will try!

Answer (score 0):

Put your form in `new.html.erb` instead of `create.html.erb` like:

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @setting  do |f| %>

#Your stuff

<% end %>
```

Your new action then be:

**new action**

```
def new
 @setting = Setting.new
end
```

Your controller then be-

**create action:**

UPDATE:

```
def create
  if request.setting?
     @setting = Setting.new(params[:setting])
    # other setup for save
    if @setting.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Setting was successfully created.'
      redirect_to @setting
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end 
end
```

**NOTE:** There is no such thing as `create.html.erb` when you say create is a post method. Also you should use `@setting` throughout your code instead of `@settings` as what it defined in a new method of controller.

Comment: i Tried it but still not helping

Comment: You haven't tried that fully. See my note in the reply. Just do like that. No `create.html.erb` whatsoever and no plurals.

Comment: Sorry, Just changed `@setting = Setting.new(params[:settings])` to `@setting = Setting.new(params[:setting])`. See the update. It should work now.

Comment: ok I created a new html file new.html.erb and put the code with singular 'setting' throughout.but still not helping

Comment: .please check and let me know if there is anyother changes to be done

Comment: ok one more change to do. Remove last line `resources :settings` from `routes.rb` and run your app. If prob persists then show me error log.

Comment: ok I changed the create action. See the update. Also remove `get 'settings/id'` from routes.rb.

Comment: ..it is still giving the same error.please let know if you want any other details